# Selected ASP Text not being Passed to VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I apologize in advance, I am familiar with programming in ASP/C#. However, my new job has some older applications using VB. I cannot for the life of me get the selected text to pass as a variable to my stored proc. The SQL command was created on the ASP page to pull back the Dropdown options. The VB script executes the stored proc.

**ASP**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFacultyAssign" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="FacultyAssign" Visible="false" 
DataTextField="FULLNAME" DataValueField="FULLNAME" AutoPostBack="true" 
AppendDataBoundItems="true">                                                
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**VB**

```
MyCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FACASSIGN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255))

MyCommand.Parameters("@FACASSIGN").Value = Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedItem.Text
```

Comment: Try `MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@FACASSIGN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) 
MyCommand.Parameters("@FACASSIGN").Value = Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedItem.Text` OrElse `MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@FACASSIGN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedItem.Text`. Also if you want the selected item try `Me.ddlFacultyAssign.SelectedItem.Value`. You left out your binding as well and I dont see where you are setting the datasource.

Comment: So this is what I am not sure of because when this was originally written they were doing all of their data connections on the asp page, Would I do the binding and setting the source in the VB script as well?

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FacultyAssign" runat="server"
                                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SOCCConnectionString %>" 
                                                    SelectCommand="EXEC SOCC.dbo.sp_util_FacultyAssign @PEOPLE_CODE_ID">